How to put all themes dictionary in one xaml file
I was wondering if it is possible to put all themes in one file? If I want to call theme A, I will just assign Theme A value to the DynamicResource. Is it possible?
Previously I was using 5 different theme files and everytime I will change the resource file name from Theme A to other Theme names when it is needed. So I was wondering if I can put all these configuration in one file instead of having multiple theme files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-merged-dictionaries?view=netdesktop-8.0
